# Understanding the operation count of this algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms

I wish to know how to correctly compute the operation count in flops for this algorithm

$\mathsf{for\;j = 1 : n}$

$\quad\mathsf{for\;k= 1 : j}$

$\quad\quad\mathsf{T(1:k,j)=T(1:k,j)+B(k,j)*A(1:k,j)}$

$\mathsf{end\;all\;loops}$

Computing the operation count was challenging for me in this case because I am not sure whether what I did was write or not :
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{F}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}2\;(\text{or is it $1+k$?})
\end{align*}
I would hope for some assistance on this. I would suspect it is $1+k$ because we are performing a constant*vector operation $\mathsf{B(k,j)*A(1:k,j)}$ which is $k$ flops and we are doing one addition.

Comment: When j= 1 the loop "k= 1:j" runs once.  When j= 2, it runs twice, etc.  So it runs a total of 1+ 2+ 3+ ...+n= n(n+1)/2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop does a linear update $$y \gets y + \alpha x$$ where $x$ and $y$ are vectors of length $k$ and $\alpha$ is a constant. Hence the number of basic arithmetic operations in the inner loop is $k$ multiplications and $k$ additions. The total number of basic arithmetic operations is $$T = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^j 2k = \sum_{j=1}^n j(j+1)= \frac{1}{3}n(n+1)(n+2).$$
In reality, the linear update will be executed as a loop and you have three nested loops. It is therefore not surprising that the total number of arithmetic operations is $O(n^3)$.